# Jquery State Pending

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm experiencing a bit of a strange behaviour when making an ajax request with Jquery, the request stays forever in 'pending' state.

As you can see I AM getting the 200 Ok status back, but I have no idea what else it wants.

Any help would be appretiated.

Its a very simple GET request:

```
function validateZipcode(event){
  definitionObj = j(this).data("definition");
  url = baseUrl+"/address/ajax/validateZip/zipcode/"+this.value;
  ajaxObj = j.ajax({url: url,success:function(result){
     handleValidateZip(result.evalJSON(),definitionObj);
  }});
 } `
```

Raw HTTP response headers are as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 11 Dec 2013 05:30:30 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.4 (Unix) PHP/5.4.19 OpenSSL/1.0.1e mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.19
Set-Cookie: DBGSESSID=1%3Bd%3D1%2Cp%3D0; path=/; version=1
frontend=1jtnhn5g02vt7nhvmm0ekomb55; expires=Wed, 11-Dec-2013 06:30:31 GMT; path=/somePath;     domain=SomeDomain.com; httponly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
P3p: CP="CAO PSA OUR"
Status: 200 OK
Content-Length: 96
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

And the contents follows:
    `{"city":"N\/A","state":"DISTRITO FEDERAL","colonies":["HERMANOS SERDAN","PERIODISTA"],"ok":true}`

**EDIT:** I don't think the server side code is relevant in this case, but here it is:

```
 class GattacaWebLab_Addressvalidation_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
    {

        /**
        * Returns a JSON object with the state corresponding to the zip and cities that belong to the zip
        * @throws Exception
        */
        public function validateZipAction()
        {
            $zipcode=$this->getRequest()->getParam('zipcode');

            $colonyCollection = Mage::getModel('addressvalidation/colony')->getCollection();
            $colonyCollection->addFieldToFilter('ZIP', $zipcode);
            $cityName=$colonyCollection->getFirstItem()->getCity()->getData('CIUDAD');
            $stateName=$colonyCollection->getFirstItem()->getState()->getData('ESTADO');
            $colonies = array();

            foreach($colonyCollection as $colony)
            {
                $colonies[]=$colony->getData('COLONIA');
            }

            if(sizeof($colonies)>0)            
                $response = array('city' => $cityName, 
                    'state' => $stateName,
                    'colonies'=>$colonies,
                    'ok' => true,
                );
            else
                $response = array('ok'=>false);

            $response=Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response);

            $this->getResponse()
            ->setHeader("Status","200 OK",true)
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->setBody($response);

            //And voilá mon ami! C'est fini


        }

    }
```

Comment: can you paste your zipcode file code here?? and status 200 mins you have received response. which pending state you are talking about?

Comment: In firebug, while debugging, I run ajaxObj.state() on the console and it says 'pending'

Comment: in the file which you are calling you should print your data and put die; to check if there is any error on that page in firebug console.

Comment: I dont think there's an error, because there is a response body, and its correct. I mean the JSON data recieved is correct.

Comment: It works alright with me I copied the code and checked I put alert instead of handleValidateZip..

Answer (score 0):

Three possibilities jump to mind:

1. You aren't loading the page from baseUrl, so you are getting a cross-origin error.
2. There's an error occurring in the Ajax processing, but you don't have an error callback, so it's silenced.
3. There's an error in your success callback (does the result object really have a getJSON function?) that you're not noticing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.<br><ol>
<li> How can I check this? I believe its not happening, but how can I make sure?
<li> How can I specify one?
<li>The callback never gets called, I put a breakpoint to it and it never ran.
</ol>

Comment: How can you check for a cross-origin request?  You either have it or you don't.  Is the domain of the *page* the same as the domain of the request?  Also, add an error callback, see if it's called.